# cannot get response from postman post

Tags: node.js, web-services, postman

I have the following code in my routes file:

```
$http.post(myConfig.api_url + '/find_produit',  {location: $scope.search.dep}
```

I am making a post call from postman with following details:

url :

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/api/find_produit/
```

and attributes :

```
dep : Paris
```

and header i have tried :

```
Content-Type:application/json
```

but it output this :

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

so can any help me please.

Comment: Whether your API(Web service) got the request???

Comment: Can you share your server side?

Comment: sorry @Avihaym , i can't share more than that because the code is confidential.

Comment: @nassim then have some console statements and check whether your server is able to receive request.

Comment: You have your server side code right?? Then in that for the route what you have specified put some console.log(), and see whether its printing???

Comment: ok i will test that

Comment: @nassim Its hard to help you without see your code.

Comment: Try Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: @Subburaj i have put console .log() and output this  :  java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to www.mywebsite.com/82.103.84.4 (port 443): isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Comment: @nassim Means your server code is not running....